# How does one access a different subscription from a runbook

Tags: azure, powershell, authentication, runbook

Currently, I have two subscriptions: S01 and S02. I have a runbook running in S02 that needs to access resources in S01.

When I run the command `Get-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionName S01`, it fails to even find the subscription. Below is an example of code and output:

```
$connectionName = "AzureRunAsConnection"
try
{
    # Get the connection "AzureRunAsConnection "
    $servicePrincipalConnection = Get-AutomationConnection -Name $connectionName         

    Write-Output "Logging in to Azure..."
    $Account = Add-AzureRmAccount `
        -ServicePrincipal `
        -TenantId $servicePrincipalConnection.TenantId `
        -ApplicationId $servicePrincipalConnection.ApplicationId `
        -CertificateThumbprint $servicePrincipalConnection.CertificateThumbprint `
        -Verbose `
        -ErrorAction Stop

    Write-Output "***** LOGGED IN ($((Get-AzureRmContext).Subscription.SubscriptionName)). *******"
}
catch {
    if (!$servicePrincipalConnection)
    {
        $ErrorMessage = "Connection $connectionName not found."
        throw $ErrorMessage
    } 
    else
    {
        Write-Error -Message $_.Exception
        throw $_.Exception
    }
}

 Write-Output "Current subscription using Get-AzureRmSubscription:"
 Get-AzureRmSubscription
 Write-Output "==============================================================="

 Write-Output "Switch subscription using Select-AzureRmSubscription:"
 Get-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionName "S01" | Select-AzureRmSubscription
 Write-Output "==============================================================="

 Write-Output "Switch subscription using Set-AzureRmContext:"
 Set-AzureRmContext -SubscriptionName "S01"
 Write-Output "==============================================================="
```

Output:

```
Logging in to Azure...

VERBOSE: Performing the operation "log in" on target "ServicePrincipal account in environment 'AzureCloud'".

***** LOGGED IN (S02). *******

Current subscription using Get-AzureRmSubscription:

WARNING: Unable to acquire token for tenant 'Common'

SubscriptionId            : 2f301a20-22a3-b321-2a3c-829ac3d4e39a
SubscriptionName          : S02
State                     : Enabled
TenantId                  : e2g374a3-8732-3466-9876-a7cd32b208de
CurrentStorageAccountName : 

===============================================================

Switch subscription using Select-AzureRmSubscription:

WARNING: Unable to acquire token for tenant 'Common'

ERROR: Get-AzureRmSubscription : Subscription S01 was not found in tenant . Please verify that the subscription 
exists in this tenant.
At line:37 char:2
+  Get-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionName "S01" | Sele ...
+  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Get-AzureRmSubscription], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Profile.GetAzureRMSubscriptionCommand


===============================================================

Switch subscription using Set-AzureRmContext:

ERROR: Set-AzureRmContext : Provided subscription S01 does not exist
At line:41 char:2
+  Set-AzureRmContext -SubscriptionName "S01"
+  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Set-AzureRmContext], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Profile.SetAzureRMContextCommand


===============================================================
```

I guess it all revolves around the AzureRunAsConnection and AzureRunAsCertificate and using the ServicePrincipal. My guess is that I need to log in using S01's AzureRunAsConnect which I assume means I need to get the certificate out of S01 and into S02, but I am not having much luck exporting and importing the RunAsCertificate from S01, into S02.

I've tried creating my own AD Application, but I can't seem to get that to work either.

I'm sure it has to be possible, but how? Am I close and what is the correct way?

P.S. Both subscriptions "share" the same Azure AD.

TIA

Answer (score 1):

You can't export once assigned certificate to Service Principal. So you have two options:

1. Create a new service principal with a certificate and use the same certificate for both subscriptions
2. If you have a copy of existing service principal's certificate then use it to authenticate to your second Azure subscription.

No matter which approach you choose, you should take a look here for step by step description of creating service principal, certificate, etc.: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-sec-configure-azure-runas-account#update-an-automation-account-using-powershell

Comment: Thanks. So, I'm on the right path. I was  kinda following that page, but I hit a snag around "AsymmetricX509Cert". Even though I was running the script on Windows 10, that has the right version of the PKI module. If I recall correctly, I need to install something to give me the right namespace. I'll have another go and report back. Thanks.

Comment: Try to comment out:  

#$KeyCredential.Type = "AsymmetricX509Cert"
#$KeyCredential.Usage = "Verify"

It worked for me.